# How to send upload image through email

Tags: php, email

I need to be able to send image that is uploaded into form when hit submit it sends email.

The problem that is happening is it sends email with text but photos are not going through. What do I do differently?

```
$email_to = "email@email.com";
$email_subject = "Subject";
$email_from = "People";
        
$b_frontPhoto = $_FILES['before1']; // required
$b_backPhoto = $_FILES['before2']; // required 
$b_sidePhoto = $_FILES['before3']; // required
$s_Weight = $_POST['startWeight']; // not required
$s_pantSize = $_POST['startPants']; // required
$s_dressSize = $_POST['startDress']; // required
// $why_start = $_POST['bwell_code']; // required

$email_message = "Form details below.<br><br>";

$email_message .= "Name: ".$b_frontPhoto."<br>";
$email_message .= "Address: ".$b_backPhoto."<br>";
$email_message .= "City: ".$b_sidePhoto."<br>";
$email_message .= "State: ".$s_Weight."<br>";
$email_message .= "Zip: ".$s_pantSize."<br>";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$s_dressSize."<br>";
// $email_message .= "Redemption_Code: ".$b_redemption."<br>";
    
sendEmail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,'email@email.com');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should really invest some time looking into PHPMailer as it will make your life much easier from now on. It fixes tons of problems that PHP mail() has, such as adding the ability to easily add an attachment, and it's extremely simple to use.

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

In the following example, you'd attach your image by calling the addAttachment and supplying your image URL, which can be the file you just uploaded:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

EDIT:

Based off the comments you are using PHPMailer already so alter the sendEmail function like so:

```
function sendEmail($email,$subject,$content,$sent_from_email_address,$b_frontPhot‌​o,$b_backPhoto,$b_si‌​dePhoto) {
///////////////////////////////// Passed the photos to the function ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        $b_frontPhot‌​o = $b_frontPhot‌​o['tmp_name'];
        $b_backPhot‌​o = $b_backPhot‌​o['tmp_name'];
        $b_sidePhot‌​o = $b_sidePhot‌​o['tmp_name'];
//^^^^^^ Try adding these in ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $mail = new PHPMailer();  
        $mail->IsSMTP();  
        $mail->Host = "stuff";  
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;      
        $mail->Username = "stuuff";
        $mail->Password = "stuff";
        $mail->Port = "stuff";       
        $mail->setFrom($sent_from_email_address, "stuff");
        $mail->Encoding = "stuff";  
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($content); 
        $mail->AddAddress($email); 

        // Attach the files to the email
        $mail->addAttachment($b_frontPhoto);
        $mail->addAttachment($b_backPhoto);
        $mail->addAttachment($b_sidePhoto);


        if (!$mail->Send()) 
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
}///// close function /////
```

Comment: Okay, so I am super new and have no idea what I am doing. But i am fairly certain I am using PHPMailer.

Comment: I don't quite understand what I need to do.

Comment: Like i guess my question is do I need to make the file /var/tmp/file.tar.gz or  '/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'. Like if i just copy that will it work?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what you are using as the function sendEmail is not native to PHP nor to PHPMailer.

Comment: this what it look like

Comment: function sendEmail($email,$subject,$content,$sent_from_email_address)
{
        $mail = new PHPMailer();  
  $mail->IsSMTP();  
  $mail->Host = "stuff";  
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
  $mail->Username = "stuuff";
  $mail->Password = "stuff";
  $mail->Port = "stuff";    
  $mail->setFrom($sent_from_email_address, "stuff");
  $mail->Encoding = "stuff";  
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->msgHTML($content); 
  $mail->AddAddress($email);   
  if (!$mail->Send()) 
         return 0;
     else
   return 1;
}///// close function /////

Comment: for some reason it said edit cant be shown unless "peer review" but that is what it was

Comment: Gotcha, you are using PHPMailer. Add the file names to the function variables like this sendEmail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,'email@email.com',$b_frontPhoto,$b_backPhoto,$b_sidePhoto) and add the following for each photo inside the function: $mail->addAttachment($b_frontPhoto); (add 2 more, for the other photos)

Comment: Still not seeming to work.. Is it supposed to be this $b_frontPhoto = $_FILES['before1'];? or should it be  $b_frontPhot‌​o = $b_frontPhot‌​o['name'];

Comment: Since $b_frontPhoto = $_FILES['before1'] the following $b_frontPhot‌​o['tmp_name'] is the same $_FILES['before1']['tmp_name']. It HAS to be 'tmp_name' by the way, don't change that.

Comment: I feel like we are so close! but it is still not sending the photos

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($b_frontPhot‌​o) for each photo inside of the sendEmail function and let me know what it shows

Comment: Alright so i put that in and ran the form again and it said "NULL"

Comment: Your images from the form are not uploading for some reason. Make sure that your input names match your PHP variables `<input type="file" name="before1">`

Comment: Currently looks like this           <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <label class="input-group-btn"> <span class="btn btn-grn rip"> Choose file
              <input name="before1" type="file" style="display:none;" multiple>
              </span> </label>
          </div>

Comment: Remove the `multiple` from the input and make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` added to the `<form>`

Comment: YUP that is it. You are a genius. Thank you a million times dawg! Take it easy.